# Regular expression in Python to split a string based on characters that begin with @ and end with :?

Tags: python, regex, string, list, split

I have strings that look like this:

```
sentences = "@en:The dog went for a walk@es:El perro fue de paseo"
```

Desired output:

```
splitted = ['The dog went for a walk', 'El perro fue de paseo']
```

Current code:

```
splitted = re.split("^@:$", sentences)
```

So, id like to split the sentences based on characters beginning with an add symbol **@** and ending with a colon **:** , as these are the way all languages are encoded, e.g. (@en:, @es:, @fr:, @nl: etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split on from @ to : without matching any of those chars in between using a negated character class.

There might be empty entries in the result, which you can filter out.

```
@[^@:]*:
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/leYq0k/1)

```
import re
sentences = "@en:The dog went for a walk@es:El perro fue de paseo"
splitted = [s for s in re.split("@[^@:]*:", sentences) if s]

print(splitted)
```

Output

```
['The dog went for a walk', 'El perro fue de paseo']
```

Comment: From my point of view, it is safe to assume that an interesting `@` is always followed by letters - use `+` instead (+1 nevertheless).

Comment: @Jan Looking the the example data, you might be right. I will leave it like how it currently is to keep all the answers different.

Answer (score 1):

hello try this code it will help you

```
import re
sentences = "@en:The dog went for a walk@es:El perro fue de paseo" 
splitted = re.split(r"@[a-zA-z]+:",sentences)  
print(splitted)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You need this regex : `@[^@:]+:`

first, `@` match a `@`

next, `[^@:]+` match any number of characters (minimum one) that are not `@` or `:`

finally, `:` match a `:`

```
import re
sentences = "@en:The dog went for a walk@es:El perro fue de paseo"
splitted = re.split("@[^@:]+:", sentences)
print(splitted[1:])
```

output:

```
['The dog went for a walk', 'El perro fue de paseo']
```